# advantages of using puppetmaster over git pull

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I am currently setting up puppet for a network of around 30 servers in a master / agent setup, but since I am using the open source version of puppet, is there really any advantage of using a puppetmaster?

I have to ssh to the server to set up the puppet agent anyway, so why not setting up a cronjob that pulls directly from github (a 'release branch' maybe?) and applies certificates directly seems also very attractive.

Are there any significant advantages of using a open source puppetmaster? Since `puppet kick` got deprecated, I can't think of any that come out of the box.